# Как разрешить вводить неопределённые данные input в python?

Tags: python

Нужно сделать код, в котором пользователь будет выбирать сервис, с которым будет работать, например, StuckOverflow:

```
A = input("Что выбираете? [StuckOv./YouTube]: ")
```

Нужно, что бы пользователь мог не вводить полностью название сервиса, а сокращать (Ст.Ов/St.Ov), или, например, "по-русски" написать сервис (Ютуб, стаковерфлоу), и желательно, что бы на регистр тоже не обращалось внимания. При этом, если он напишет другой сервис (Гитхаб, например), то программа выводила ошибку. Возможно ли сделать это? Или придётся делать словарь определённых слов?

Comment: вопрос у вас не "как вводить", а "как обрабатывать".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы не мучать пользователя предлагаю реализовать как меню:

```
print("Сервис:")
print("1. StuckOv")
print("2. YouTube")
A = input("Что выбираете? : ")
```

тут уже обрабатывать введённое значение 1 или 2 иначе - ошибка

Comment: Неплохое решение, спасибо

Comment: помечайте как решение и закрывайте вопрос:)